How to Remove Tagged Images from a PDF using PDFBox in Android java
I am developing an Android application where I need to add and remove images from a PDF document. I am using the PDFBox library for this purpose. I have successfully added images to the PDF with a specific tag, but I am struggling to remove them based on their tag. Despite attempting various approaches, the image remains in the document.
Here's what I have tried so far:

Adding Images with Tags: I am able to add images to specific pages of the PDF and assign a tag to each image for identification.

private void appendImageToPdf(int id, int pageNumber, String tag) throws IOException {
    InputStream input = getContentResolver().openInputStream(pdfUri);
    PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(input);
    PDPage page = document.getPage(pageNumber);

    PDRectangle pageSize = page.getMediaBox();
    pageWidth = pageSize.getWidth();
    pageHeight = pageSize.getHeight();

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), id);
    PDImageXObject pdImage = LosslessFactory.createFromImage(document, bitmap);

    float imageWidth = 70;
    float imageHeight = 70;
    float x = (pageWidth - imageWidth) / 2;
    float y = (pageHeight - imageHeight) / 2;

    PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, true, true);
    contentStream.drawImage(pdImage, x, y, imageWidth, imageHeight);
    imagePositions.add(new ImageDetails((int) x, (int) y, (int) imageWidth, (int) imageHeight, pageNumber, tag));

    COSDictionary imageDictionary = pdImage.getCOSObject();
    imageDictionary.setString(COSName.getPDFName("Tag"), tag);

    contentStream.close();
    File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "updated.pdf");
    document.save(file);
    document.close();
    input.close();
    pdfUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    displayPdf(pdfUri, currentPage);
}


Removing Images by Tag: Here is the method I am using to remove images from the PDF based on their tag. Despite running this method, the images remain in the document.

private void removeImageFromPdf(String tag) throws IOException {
    InputStream input = getContentResolver().openInputStream(pdfUri);
    PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(input);
    for (PDPage page : document.getPages()) {
        COSDictionary pageDict = page.getCOSObject();
        COSBase contents = pageDict.getItem(COSName.CONTENTS);
        if (contents instanceof COSArray) {
            COSArray contentsArray = (COSArray) contents;
            removeTagFromContents(contentsArray, tag);
        } else if (contents instanceof COSObject) {
            COSBase actualBase = ((COSObject) contents).getObject();
            if (actualBase instanceof COSArray) {
                removeTagFromContents((COSArray) actualBase, tag);
            } else if (actualBase instanceof COSStream) {
                removeTagFromStream((COSStream) actualBase, tag);
            }
        } else if (contents instanceof COSStream) {
            removeTagFromStream((COSStream) contents, tag);
        }
    }

    File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "updated.pdf");
    document.save(file);
    document.close();
    input.close();
    pdfUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    displayPdf(pdfUri, currentPage);
}

private void removeTagFromContents(COSArray contents, String tag) throws IOException {
    for (int i = 0; i < contents.size(); i++) {
        COSBase base = contents.getObject(i);
        if (base instanceof COSDictionary) {
            COSDictionary dict = (COSDictionary) base;
            COSString cosTag = (COSString) dict.getItem(COSName.getPDFName("Tag"));
            if (cosTag != null && tag.equals(cosTag.getString())) {
                contents.remove(i);
                i--; // Decrement the index to account for the removal
            }
        } else if (base instanceof COSStream) {
            removeTagFromStream((COSStream) base, tag);
        }
    }
}

private void removeTagFromStream(COSStream stream, String tag) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byteArrayOutputStream.write(stream.getUnfilteredStream().readAllBytes());
    String content = byteArrayOutputStream.toString();
    byteArrayOutputStream.close();

    // Implement logic to remove tagged content from the stream's content string
    // This is a complex task and requires parsing the PDF content stream

    // Example: Removing tagged content (simplified, real implementation needed)
    content = content.replaceAll("/Tag \\(" + tag + "\\).*?EI", "");

    stream.removeItem(COSName.LENGTH);
    stream.setItem(COSName.LENGTH, new COSString(String.valueOf(content.length())));
    stream.setData(content.getBytes());
}

Questions:

How can I correctly remove the tagged images from the PDF?
Is there a better approach to tagging and identifying images for removal in PDFBox?

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
